# IPv6 to IPv4 converting - tunnel between to ubuntu servers

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-networking

I live in a country that recently launched a heavy censorship protocol on Internet.
most of the IPv4s are restricted or completely banned.

I have two servers , one in my country and another one in Germany that has access to free internet.

I need to figure something like this

using this command to make the tunnel :

ssh -v -N -f -L [local_ipv6_address]:[local_port]:[remote_ipv6_address]:[remote_port] [user]@[server]

but the tunnel needs to be translated atleast at the client side (my ISP doesnt support IPv6)
I need a help to do that.

````
                      _____                           _____
                      \ | /      (IPv6-ssh tunnel)    \ | /                                   
                       \|/  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  \|/  
                        |                               |                                    
                   ---------                       ----------                               
                   |  VPN   |                      |  sever |                              
free internet------| server |                      |  in my |-----------clients         
                   |Germany |                      |country |                      
```                ----------                      ----------
````

Comment: You can tunnel IPv6 over IPv4-ssh connection. There's no translation needed - the client to server connection can run over IPv4, and transport IPv6 packets.

Comment: hell yes it works!

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSH can create a Socks Proxy (`-D <port-number>` cmd line argument) that can be used to tunnel most traffic.

e.g. you can enable a socks proxy for Chrome with the following cmd line argument `--proxy-server="socks5://myproxy:8080"` where `myproxy` would be your local server and `8080` would be the port number passed to the `-D` argument.